# WP71 MVVMLight EventTrigger not recognised

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, windows-phone-7.1

Having followed Laurent's upgrade guide http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/mangobeta/ to get from an existing MVVMLight WP7 project to a WP71 project. I have changed the references and namespaces corectly. But the EventTrigger is not recognised in the XAML

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>

        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <cmd:EventToCommand 
                Command="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Path=LoadedCommand}"
                 PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

I get an error on the EventTrigger element.

Has it changed?

Comment: I would add a tag for WP71 but I dont have the rep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this exact same problem when I upgrade my application from WP7 to WP7.1(Mango). The problem was the MVVM Light Binaries. You need to upgrade to the WP7.1 Binaries.

Laurent Bugnion ( https://stackoverflow.com/users/12233/lbugnion ) explains how to upgrade the MVVM Light binaries on his website here: http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/mangobeta/

These are the essential steps I used to fix my problem:

- [Download the most recent version from here](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).
- Open and Compile the WP71 project.
- Copy the binaries to your MVVM Binary location (in my case C:\Program Files\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries)
- Open your project
- In the References folder, delete GalaSoft.MvvmLight, GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras and System.Windows.Interactivity.
- Add the new references from the folder C:\Program Files\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Binaries\WP71.

Comment: +1 Thanks a ton! That saved me a lot of code- and xaml-refactoring. I thought it would no longer work that way with wp7.1, but in fact you just need the new mvvmlight binaries.

Comment: Adding a comment for when I forget / if anyone else has this issue -- Resharper seems to incorrectly resolve EventTrigger in the global namespace rather than the Interactivity namespace. I didn't notice because EventTrigger & i:EventTrigger look very similar. I just spent 4 hours frustrated trying to figure it out. Don't let it happen to you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem after upgrading to Mango. In my case, I had the EventToCommand binding on a MenuItem click, but you seem to have it on some sort of loaded event. You could try using an anonymous delegate in the loaded evcent from the view's code-bhind. Ie:

```
this.Loaded+=(s,e)=>ViewModel.LoadedCommand.Execute(null);
```

In  my case, I changed from:

```
<tk:MenuItem Header="Delete Snapshot" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
            <mvvmLight:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DeleteSnapshotCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=lstSnapshots}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</tk:MenuItem>
```

to

```
<tk:MenuItem Header="Delete Snapshot" Command="{Binding DeleteSnapshotCommand, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem,ElementName=lstSnapshots}" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering,yes I could use code-behind, but I am trying to keep a clean MVVM implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved on from this issue, by reverting back to pre-mango dev environment. 
Not the solution I wanted, but - onwards and forwards.